# Home router for higher network loads

Tags: router, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I'm trying to find a replacement for my ASUS WL500GP router.

Some constraints:

- my ISP now provides 120 Mbit bandwidth - the router must be able to handle it
- I have 3 computers and a laptop at home - the router must have at least 4 LAN ports and the WAN port
- I need to be able to do the following in parallel:

  - use bittorrent with ~1000 connections
  - transfer files from one home computer to another at high speed
  - access one home computer from my workplace
- I don't really need wireless
- I don't really want two boxes to serve all these purposes.

So I was searching for a router with 1 Gbit ports, jumbo frame support and good reviews, but haven't really found a promising candidate so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 120 MBit bandwidth?  Who's your ISP?!

Comment: It's UPC in Hungary. Their offer (in Hungarian, but you'll understand it I guess :-D):

http://www.upc.hu/kabel-internet/fiber-power-120/

Comment: I can't read Hungarian, but I got the general gist of the page.  I live in the US, and I'm stuck with 1.5Mbit/768Kbit DSL.

Comment: they don't include a router in the package ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following models work for you

linksys-wrt610n
-wrvs4400n
rvs4000    - cheap

Answer (score 0):

the ASUS RT-N56U (or the 66) is the fastest home router on the market

Answer (score 0):

You require more than mass-market consumer hardware, so first stop looking at that market filled with attractive packaging and empty promises.

I filled similar requirement using a [Fabiatech FX5624](http://www.fabiatech.com/en/product-c.php?id=60) which I acquired from [Mini-ITX.com](http://www.mini-itx.com/store/?c=40#FX5624). It is wholly fanless and features 2xGb Ethernet + 4x100Mb Ethernet. I run it as a VLAN switch on the trunked Gb Ethernet ports, as a richly featured border router with my ISP on one 100Mb Ethernet port and it took all the network loads I could throw at it without a hitch. If you want even more Gigabit Ethernet ports, the [Fabiatech FX5625](http://www.mini-itx.com/store/?c=40#FX5625) has eight of them. I run Debian on that host and I get it to do anything I can imagine - I love networking with Debian !

But building a router from scratch with Debian may not be your cup of tea. So if you require solid performance from something that will work out of the box, take a look at products from Mikrotik, such as the [RB2011L](http://routerboard.com/RB2011UAS-IN) series - the OS is proprietary but that is probably what I would choose if I had to deploy a packaged solution in a hurry - I particularly like how they are transparent about the hardware's performance and the OS's functionnality.